# How to generate a sequence for a grid of values, instead of a straight line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, grid

Sequences need to be

```
- `a0grid`  including increments of 100 between starting at 500 and up to 2500 [500,600,700,...,2200,2300,2400,2500] 
- `a1grid` including increments of 10  between -100 and 100 [-100,-90,-80,...,80,90,100]
```

Initialization:

```
a0 <- seq(500,2500,by=100)
a1 <- seq(-100,100,by=10)

 [1]  500  600  700  800  900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500
 [1] -100  -90  -80  -70  -60  -50  -40  -30  -20  -10    0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

What I'm getting right now:

[image]

What I'm looking for (not exactly, but just points everywhere as shown):

[image]

Comment: what is the code that you are using for the plot ?

Comment: `data.frame(a0,a1) %>% ggplot() +
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=a0,y=a1))` Using geom_point only

Comment: @RonakShah geom_point only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `expand.grid` if you want points everywhere

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(expand.grid(a0, a1)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Var1,y=Var2))
```

[image]

---

This plot could also be done without any packages

```
plot(expand.grid(a0, a1), pch = 16)
```

[image]